# neo4j browser reports completely unrealistic runtime

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j community 4.2.1, playing with graph databases. I plan to operate on lots of data and want to get familiar with indexes and stuff.
However, I'm stuck at a very basic level because in the browser Neo4j reports query runtimes which have nothing to do with reality.

I'm executing the following query in the browser at http://localhost:7687/:

```
match (m:Method),(o:Method) where m.name=o.name and m.name <> '<init>' and 
m.signature=o.signature and toInteger(o.access)%8 in [1,4]
return m,o
```

The DB has ~5000 Method labels.

The browser returns data after about 30sec. However, Neo4j reports

```
Started streaming 93636 records after 1 ms and completed after 42 ms, displaying first 1000 rows.
```

Well, 42ms and 30sec is really far away from each other! What am I supposed to do with this message? Did the query take only milliseconds and the remaining 30secs were spent rendering the stuff in the browser? What is going on here? How can I improve my query if I cannot even tell how long it really ran?

I modified the query, returning `count(m) + count(n)` instead of `m,n` which changed things, now runtime is about 2secs and Neo4j reports about the same amount.

Can somebody tell me how I can get realistic runtime figures of my queries without using the stop watch of my cell?

Comment: Are you returning a lot of data... neo4j browser can behave weird when you return a lot of data. Also make sure to untick connect result nodes in neo4j browser

Comment: You can also try `RETURN count(*)` and compare the runtimes there. If that returns fast, then the longer time is likely being spent with projecting properties and sending them across the wire and having the Browser interpret and display the results. You may also want to try running this via cypher-shell, the command-line interface, to see the difference when you don't require retrieving and displaying the results in a web browser.